# My flutter project broke and I get this gradle error

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
> Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried so many things I changed flutter and gradle version and looked everywhere but I still get this error. It worked before now it just doesen't. Btw java version is set to 1.8

Comment: In general, it can be worth it to do `File --> Invalidate Caches and Restart`, see if that fixes things. Though the answer below seems plausible

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

Solution:

1. Downgrade flutter version from 2.2.3 to 2.2.2
2. Delete ~/.android folder.
3. Restart android studio.

Comment: .android folder that is in my c:users or in project folder

Comment: the one in the project folder you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error has like a hundreds reason no one can know except to remember what you had done before. But anyway for better solution follow the following:

- go to tools tab then flutter clean
- go to file tab then invalidate cache and restart
- follow the steps [in this article](https://medium.com/@gtxgat/upgrade-gradle-version-professionally-in-flutter-5e0c16305cc0) to have the latest updates from Gradle
- finally go to android folder then build gradle then on top right you will see edit file or something similar .. press on it and open new window and let it auto update till the end .. and better if you go to file into that new window then select project structure and manually see what the warning will it show to you and only press update

And don't forget to use the latest Flutter SDK.